# Handle Button click Listener in RecyclerView

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview, fragment

I'm trying to use onClickListener for Button Inside my RecyclerView row and I also have click listener for my RecyclerView row, now the problem is if I click the Button on a row of the RecyclerView it's also fired the click listener of RecyclerView row, By the way here i'm using a fragment.

This is custom class for RecyclerView touchListener

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private ClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));

    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}

public static  interface ClickListener {

    void onClick(View view, int position);
    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}
```

}

this is ViewHolder for Buttons

```
 public static class RecycleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageButton BTN_B, BTN_A, BTN_C;

    public RecycleViewHolder(View view){

        super(view);

        ItemImage      = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_item_image);

        BTN_A = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_a);
        BTN_B = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_b);
        BTN_C = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_c);

       BTN_B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(CTX,"B Button Clicked"+getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        BTN_A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(CTX,"A Button Clicked"+getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        BTN_C.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(CTX,"C Button Clicked"+getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing click event for whole recycler view, get the parent element of child layout of recycler view and add on click event for it like you added for BTN_A,BTN_B,BTN_C,

for example if parent element of child layout of recycler view(the topmost view in child layout) is a relative layout add onclick event for relativelayout